# use of jQuery $.ajax to retrieve data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I usually use $.ajax to send data to the method in the URL. After some search, I found that I can retrieve result data. Am I looking at this the wrong way? I need a proper explanation of it's use, please.

Also, if I want to retrieve more or different data than ones in the "data:" field, what do I do? And what's the use of the "context:" field?

```
$.ajax({
  url: getById,
  type: 'POST',
  context: document.body,
  async: false,  
  data: {
    id : id.val(),
    name : name.val()
  },
  success:function(data) {
    // do something with the retrieved data
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get information about the `data` parameter or on how to process results sent back from the server?

Comment: What do you expect as data in the success-function? What do you get? Ajax sends a request to the server. When the request fails, the error-function is called. If the request succeeds, the success-function is called with the data in the response. If the data follows a certain pattern, jQuery might process this data (in case of json for example). Read the documentation and after you did that, please provide more context for your question. It is very unclear what you are even trying to do.

Comment: I wanted to know the difference between the "data" field in $.ajax and the "data" parameter sent to the success function and tymeJV explained that. As for the "context" field, I still don't understand it much but I mainly needed to know about the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` can be any information passed back from the server. Typically in an `$.ajax` call that receives data back, you also specify the `dataType` paramter in the AJAX call itself. The most common would be `json`, but there are also other types (XML, HTML, etc).

If you want to retrieve more than one field, you don't add more data variables in the callback, you simply encode you data so it can be pulled out of the `data` variable. Example with JSON, you would encode `json` on the server-side with as much data as you want, then pull it out of that one `data` variable.

I suggest taking a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and reading up on it, it gives nice examples. Also, take to Google and check out returning data to jQuery AJAX call, there are multiple tutorials with different backends.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful,Get data from ID & pass it as a datastring to any page

```
  var uname=$('#uname').val();
  var password=$('#password').val();

  var dataString = 'uname='+ uname + '&password='+ password;
  $("#flash").show();
  $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/loading.gif" />');
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: // Here pass your page URL
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
           var result=trim(result);
           $("#flash").hide();
           if(result=='correct')
           {
                 // Do whatever you want
           }
          else
           {
                 // Display error message to page, if any        
                 $("#errorMessage").html(result);
           }
  }
  });
```

Comment: It might be useful with a bit of reverse engineering, but not to someone in need of a proper explanation. It made sense after reading other answers.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, "id" and "name" are arguments to your server; if you aren't retrieving a dynamic page, then you might want to use [GET](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) instead of "POST", the data you want (for your AJAX caller) is the response from the server. With [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), that response is encoded usually with one of

- [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)
- [JSON](http://json.org/)

but you can certainly just retrieve anything (including **HTML**) and use jQuery to replace say a div

```
<div id='elementId'></div>
```

content with

```
 $("#elementId").html(htmlResponse);
```

Comment: I wasn't sure which answer to accept but I understood a bit more from tymeJV's explanation. But I still appreciate yours.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What type of data are you trying to send back ? Show us the script being called

For plain text/html here is a working example https://github.com/tomtoms/ajax-jquery-php